# How to delete all Stickies notes using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, stickies

How would I write an AppleScript that deletes all Stickies notes which are currently open?

Or perhaps, where are the files stored?

I tried using Automator, but it doesn't work very well to locate elements on a wide screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Stickies** *application* does not contain an **AppleScript** *dictionary*, e.g. **Stickies.sdef** *file* and as such is not considered directly **AppleScript** *scriptable* using basic *vanilla* **AppleScript**, sans a possible few basic *commands*, i.e., `activate`, `quit`, etc.

The use of **System Events** and `application process "Stickies"`, and also using **UI Scripting** can perform some *events* when trying to talk directly to `application "Stickies"` will not work.

Looking under **macOS Catalina** the **Stickies** *application* appears to store its unsaved *notes* in:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Stickies/Data/Library/Stickies
```

They are **Rich Text Document Bundles**, with the **.rtfd** *file extension*.

---

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will close the **Stickies** *application* and **permanently delete any unsaved *notes***:

```applescript
if running of application "Stickies" then ¬
    tell application "Stickies" to quit

set unsavedStickiesFolder to the POSIX path of ¬
    ((path to home folder) as string) & ¬
    "Library/Containers/com.apple.Stickies/Data/Library/Stickies/"

set shellCMD to {¬
    "/usr/bin/find ", ¬
    unsavedStickiesFolder, ¬
    " -type d -iname '*.rtfd'"} ¬
    as string

set unsavedStickies to ¬
    paragraphs of ¬
    (do shell script shellCMD)

repeat with thisFile in unsavedStickies
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        delete item thisFile
end repeat
```

---

**Notes:**

**Do not run** the above *example* **AppleScript** *code* unless your unsaved *notes* are backed up, as they will be **permanently deleted**!  **You have been warned!**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: you are excellent. works perfectly.

Comment: I can barely read this, the formatting is abysmal. My suggested edit to improve the formatting was denied. See here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/307683 Please consider making this edit yourself.